# Setting up SAP support channel with SAProute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, hana

According to the following GCP public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/sap/docs/sap-hana-operations-guide#setting_up_your_sap_support_channel_with_saprouter)

> If you need to allow an SAP support engineer to access your SAP HANA
> systems on Google Cloud, you can do so using SAProuter. Follow these
> steps:
>
> Launch the Compute Engine VM instance that the SAProuter software will
> be installed on, and    assign an external IP address so the instance
> has internet access.
>
> Create a new, static external IP address and then assign this IP
> address to the instance.
>
> Create and configure a specific SAProuter firewall rule in your
> network. In this rule, allow only the required inbound and outbound
> access to the SAP support network, for the SAProuter instance.

**Question**

1. Use of external IP address is restricted in my environment, so I will like to know if I can used a public Load balance to achieve this.

**Context**
I have a public Loadbalancer infront of a FW, how can I use this Public Load balancer IP to setup my SAP Router in GCP? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Load Balancing Forwarding Rules to allow your External IP to access your environment.

**Internal forwarding rules** 
Internal forwarding rules forward traffic that originates inside a Google Cloud network. The clients can be in the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network as the backends, or the clients can be in a connected network.

Internal forwarding rules are used by two types of Google Cloud load balancing products:

Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing 
Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing

**External forwarding rules** 
External forwarding rules accept traffic from client systems that have internet access, including:

A client outside of Google Cloud 
A Google Cloud VM with an external IP address 
A Google Cloud VM without an external IP address using Cloud NAT or an instance-based NAT system

**[Adding a forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/using-forwarding-rules)**

Create the load balancer's forwarding rule

1. Go to the Load balancing page in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Click Create load balancer.
3. Select a load balancer type, including the traffic type and whether the load balancer faces the Internet or is internal only.
4. Click Continue.
5. Click Frontend configuration. In the New Frontend IP and port section, make the following changes:

a. Name: FORWARDING_RULE_NAME 
b. Subnetwork: SUBNET_OF_YOUR_RESERVED_IP_ADDRESS \
c. From Internal IP or from IP Address, select your pre-reserved IP address. 
Optionally, you can reserve an IP address now in this UI, or you can use an ephemeral IP address.

d. Select the protocol, port numbers, and IP version.
Only some load balancer types support IPv6.

e. Verify that there is a blue check mark next to Frontend configuration before continuing. Review this step if not.

6. Click Review and finalize. Double-check your settings.
7. Click Create.

**Using [IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tcp-forwarding-overview)** 
IAP's TCP forwarding feature lets you control who can access administrative services like SSH and RDP on your backends from the public internet. The TCP forwarding feature prevents these services from being openly exposed to the internet. Instead, requests to your services must pass authentication and authorization checks before they get to their target resource.

[IAP forwarding Step by Step setup](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)

You can also check links below for your reference. 
[Forwarding rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts?hl=en) 
[Using IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)

Comment: How is this related to the use case?

Comment: Edited answer. Previous answer was assumed that Load Balancer was outsite VPC. Hope this one help.